# Please explain the following code of a Python for

Tags: python, twitter

I found this code on a Python Twitter Tools (ptt) example:

```
query = twitter.friends.ids(screen_name = username)
for n in range(0, len(query["ids"]), 100):
    ids = query["ids"][n:n+100]
```

https://github.com/ideoforms/python-twitter-examples/blob/master/twitter-friends.py

What my understanding tells me is that the range function on the for function works somewhat like this: range(initial_value, ending_value). What does the third argument mean stand for?

Also, apparently query is a string and it's accessing the `ids` feature inside the friends feature of twitter. What I don't get is what does the `[n:n+100]` do? I don't get the `[]` after the `['ids']` (perhaps it's a dict()?) nor the ":", what's that operand?

Also, my question looks pretty bad, this is my first post. Sorry about that, I'll work on that.

Comment: I would've started here `https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range` and try to find as much possible answer as I can before asking the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional third argument to `range` is the step - in this case, the values in the range go up by 100 every iteration.

the `[:]` syntax is a slice. In this case, if `query["ids"]` is a string, it's a string slice, or substring. See the python tutorial on strings here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: ``string.get(string)`` results in a TypeError (string indices must be integers, not str).

Comment: Yes, but in the original post, the expression `query["ids"]` returns a string, which was then sliced into - `query` itself is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the third params in the range is how much to increment, 100, 200, 300, etc. The [n:n+100] is used to get a subset. Starting at n and going to n+100, similarly like range.